# Magento CMS block doesn't display in product view

Tags: magento

I have a static block that have 2 product list template in it

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="22" template="catalog/product/homelist.phtml"}

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="24" template="catalog/product/homelist.phtml"}
```

Normally, this static blocks appear normally on any 2 columns left template. However, I don't understand why when I view the product (product view page is also a 2 columns left template), this block doesn't appear?

My old store runs on Magento 1.3 and there's no problem with showing this block in product view page.

The current Magento version that I'm running is 1.6.1.0

When I look into the error log, I saw something about PDO Exception. Is this error related to why my block doesn't appear on the product view page?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure those lines same in code? it should be reside in two curly brackets `{{...}}`

Comment: Do you have the file:  `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/homelist.phtml`?  (`YOUR_PACKAGE` is probably `default` and `YOUR_THEME` is the name of the theme you are using)

Comment: Yes, I do have all of that. Even the brackets are correct. I just put it wrong in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following block in (admin) cms or static block :

```
{{block type="catalog/product" category_id="22" name="custom.category" template="catalog/product/homelist.phtml"}}
```

OR

```
{{block type="catalog/product" product_id="67966" name="topnav.products" template="catalog/product/topnav-products.phtml"}}
```

Thanks,